# How to match multiple packages in btrace

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, btrace

Assuming I want to trace method calls in all the classes in packages `com.abc` and `com.def`

I put the following in my tracing script:

```
@OnMethod(clazz = "/com\\.(abc|def)\\..*/", method = "/.*/")
```

ran the script, but the output only contained method calls in `com.abc` package.

I changed the above line to:

```
@OnMethod(clazz = "/com\\.def\\..*/", method = "/.*/")
```

and ran the script again. The output contained method calls in `com.def` package.
So what's wrong with the part "`(abc|def)`"?

I've tried to find some information under the following link:

https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/wiki/BTrace-Annotations

The description is very abstract:

> /regex/ is a standard regular expression used to identify the class
>   names

Does it support OR-relation?

Comment: try this please [`com\.(abc|def)\.?.*`](https://regex101.com/r/30kRqQ/1)

Comment: @YCF_L, please use all the necessary escapings in a java file.
I've tried clazz="com\\.(abc|def)\\.?.*"
Is it correct? If yes, then result is the same - only methods in "abc" are traced.

Comment: Yes it is correct i'm sorry what you get when you use `com\\..*` do you get both `com.abc` and `com.def` ?

Comment: This is strange. I get only "com.abc". "com.def" isn't traced.

Comment: hmmm, i really don't have any idea, maybe you can share more information about your packages, or maybe we don't understand how btrace work !:{

Comment: From what is there in the code, it seems the method should be indicated. Thus, it should look like `@OnMethod(clazz = "/com\\.(abc|def)\\..*/", method = "someMethodName")`. Note that this regex actually requires a dot after `abc` or `def`, the previous comment suggested making that dot optional.

Comment: BTrace is using standard Java Pattern for regex matching. 
Tried it with the BTrace 1.3.10 and modified AllSamples script - `@OnMethod(clazz = "/javax\\.(management|swing)\\..*", method = "/.*/")` and it works as expected.